# Row auto fit not working properly

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have one excel sheet

Width of Column A is 70 and the word wrap property is ON.

And the content in the cell is of 287 words/1950 characters.
Now when i try the row autofit function, its not working properly.
Some of the content is still not visible. 
How to solve this issue.

Comment: Does it work with less (shorter) content ?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum row height is 409.

You are over that limit.

Pending the formatting of your text, including (CR) (LF) ect.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question, there is no autofit when you have word wrap on. If your text is too long then it just gets wrapped, there is nothing to fit!

If you are wondering where the rest of your text is gone then you probably need to increase your row height and you will see it.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to make a cell display all text and changing its height accordingly. Typically that's what you want in a document and on the web even more.